# Mysql database huge records

Tags: mysql, records

I have a database table which contain 100M records. I have a query that is taking 20 minutes to run - how can I make it simple and fast?

```
SELECT newnum,
       Sum(Ceil(seconds / 60)) AS ttime
FROM   astb
GROUP BY newnum
ORDER  BY ttime DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: Are you missing a GROUP BY in that query?

Comment: @Bridge yes i have indexed that table.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` work best with indexes. So if possible you could have indexes on column `newnum`.

Another point is you are making a calculation every single record in a huge table. I strongly recommend to select records in a temp table first than make your calculation on those records.

EDIT UPDATED SCRIPT: You could use temp table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS 
(SELECT newnum, SUM(seconds) AS ttime 
FROM astb GROUP BY newnum)

SELECT newnum, CEIL(ttime / 60) AS ttime
FROM temp
ORDER  BY ttime DESC 
LIMIT 100;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

Comment: ttime isn't a column, it's the result of the sum.

Comment: i have indexed this table still its taking too much time.

how can i do as temp table...

Comment: I've edited column name. If you already have indexes, it's worth trying temp table and than calculating. In this case it is quite complicated as you would like to order and limit by calculated field. I think you could try to insert sums in a temp table and then convert it seconds and order by from temp table? Does it make sense?

Comment: @huzeyfe it shows error 

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM  astb
GROUP BY newnum' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

It's not great database design, but can you add a column to hold `ceil(seconds/60)`, so you don't have to recompute it all the time?